# Web API login crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am able to use the accounts built in to web api to register a new user.  This works fine.  However when I come to then log on with any username at all, the process just hangs, never returns and locks my UI.  Can someone see anything wrong here?  The commented line is to show what I have also tried.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiUrl);
```

And then to send a logon reaquest...

```
var response = client.PostAsync("Token", new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=xxx&password=xxx1234", Encoding.UTF8)).Result;
```

It then hangs on this line above, and never returns.  I don't even know which controller method on the Web API to breakpoint because there is no obvious one.  I have tried all methods in the AccountController.cs and the ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs.  I dont even think it gets this far.

I have tried the same method I use for registering a new user and this just returns "Bad Request".

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Token", logonObject);
```

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a [common deadlock situation, due to the use of `Task<T>.Result`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). I explain the deadlock fully on my blog, but the general gist is that `await` will capture a context (in this case, the ASP.NET request context) and use that to resume its `async` method. If you block a thread in the ASP.NET request context (e.g., by calling `Task<T>.Result`), then the `async` method cannot complete.

The proper solution is to replace `Result` with `await`:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("Token", new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=xxx&password=xxx1234", Encoding.UTF8));
```

Comment: Thanks this has solved my problem!  And thanks for the blog link.